# Is there a rule to match unicode printable characters in parboiled2?

Tags: scala, unicode, character-encoding, peg, parboiled

As part of a larger parser, I am writing a rule to match strings like the following using parboiled2:

> Italiana Relè

I would like to use something simple like the following:

```
CharPredicate.Printable
```

But the parser is failing with an `org.parboiled2.ParseError` because of the unicode character at the end of the string.

Is there a simple option that I'm not aware of for matching printable unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/blob/master/parboiled-core/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/CharPredicate.scala#L112 - it is very easy to do your own predicates, for instance:

```
val latinSupplementCharsPredicate = CharPredicate('\u00c0' to '\u00dc') ++ CharPredicate('\u00e0' to '\u00fd')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had just figured that out before I saw your answer! That's so nice!

Comment: Good luck. Please also take note that different countries have different characters, so you may want to customize the Unicode selection to a specific set, and keep extra chars out to validate the data.